# How to download Adobe Fireworks CS4 now that CS5 is in the pipeline?

Tags: mac, adobe-cs4, adobe-fireworks

Last year I licensed Fireworks CS4 for Mac and downloaded the installer. I just rebuilt my computer and I need to reinstall but I can't find anywhere to download the Fireworks CS4 installer because Adobe is now promoting CS5. Where might I find it?

Comment: Since you have a licence I see *almost* no harm in visiting your favourite torrent site. But your first step should probably be to contact the customer support: http://www.adobe.com/support/service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you can contact Adobe Support. You could also attempt to find trial discs someone has laying around.

Considering there is nothing illegal about the torrent file itself (It's not pre-licensed) you could also find it on a torrent site and use your license.